# How to report MS Access data, calculated columns with group by

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, asp-classic

I have an Access 2003 database which records fault call help requests in a medium size organisation of around 200 users. Calls are logged (and appended into the database) via a Classic ASP page, and a team of systems administrators use a seperate classic ASP web page to view calls, provide a response, etc.

All calls are recorded in one table called tblFaultCall, it's structure is below

```
tblFault call
ID : Autonumber
strName
strPhone
dtmDateOpen : Date/Time (date call logged)
dtmDateClosed : Date/Time (date call closed)
dtmTime : Date/Time (time call logged)
strStatus (always 'Open', 'Pending' or 'Closed')
strCategory (always one of 10 categories, held as as list in tblCatgory, and used in lookup lists in the ASP web page)
strFaultDesc 
strResolution
strCallOwner
dtmDatePending : Date/Time (date call set to pending, if it ever was)
```

For management, I need a way of easily creating a quarterly report which shows as below

```
Call recieved between dd/mm/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy
----
Category    Calls recieved  Of which 'Closed'   closed within 5 days    Closed within 14 days   Open    Pending 
Cateogry x  1052            950                 700                     200                     50      50
Cateogry Y  65              60                  50                      5                       0       5
```

I need an easy way to do this. I need the manager to be able to insert the dates he wants, and then click a button and it all comes up. I cannot work out how to create one query which gives all of this. It's easy to give just the categories and number of Open calls, but then can't work out how to add a further column to show number of Closed calls, or the number closed within x days, etc. I can create individual queries for the harder columns, but not get it all together.

So, options are

Classic ASP - I think would involve a lot of individual SQLs for the calculated fields
Access Report ?
Some kind of export to Excel?
VBA in Excel to link back to prepared queries in Access?

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get that data in one query.  Try this one:

```
SELECT AllCalls.strCategory, CallsReceived, CallsClosed, ClosedWithin5Days, ClosedWithin14days, CallsOpen, CallsPending
FROM
((
   SELECT strCategory,
      Count(ID) AS CallsReceived,
      Sum(IIF(strStatus='Closed',1,0)) AS CallsClosed,
      Sum(IIF(strStatus='Open',1,0)) AS CallsOpen,
      Sum(IIF(strStatus='Pending',1,0)) AS CallsPending
   FROM tblFaultCall
   WHERE dtmDateOpen BETWEEN #6/1/2014# and #6/30/2014#
   GROUP BY strCategory
) AS AllCalls
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT strCategory,
      Count(ID) AS ClosedWithin5Days
   FROM tblFaultCall
   WHERE DateDiff("d", dtmDateOpen, dtmDateClosed) <=5
     AND dtmDateOpen BETWEEN #6/1/2014# and #6/30/2014#
   GROUP BY strCategory
) AS FiveDay ON AllCalls.strCategory=FiveDay.strCategory)
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT strCategory,
      Count(ID) AS ClosedWithin14Days
   FROM tblFaultCall
   WHERE DateDiff("d", dtmDateOpen, dtmDateClosed) between 5 and 14
     AND dtmDateOpen BETWEEN #6/1/2014# and #6/30/2014#
   GROUP BY strCategory
) AS FourteenDay ON AllCalls.strCategory=FourteenDay.strCategory
```

The classic ASP part should be very similar to your other pages: query the database, loop through the resulting data, output it to the screen.  You would use the same approach if you were generating a spreadsheet too.

Comment: When pasting this into Access (amending dates to  'BETWEEN #4/1/2014# AND #6/30/2014#'), I get an error 'missnig operator'.

Comment: If you try to run each of the sub-selects separately, do any of them work or can you isolate the problem to one of the sub-queries?

Comment: The GROUP BY in the first one was in wrong place, and also fixed the parenthesis (if using two LEFT JOINS the entire first one must be in it's own set), I now get the error "The specific field 'strCategory' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement". I can run the first FROM clause subselect fine, but the second one (FiveDay) would not run on its own as it was missing the GROUP BY clause. I've tried adding the group by but still get the error about strCategory. I'd put latest version in this comment but it won't let me as too long.

Comment: Gosh, you are right.  I fixed the syntax to address the things you mentioned. Try it now.

Comment: Now I get "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."

Comment: Again, when you get a syntax error, it is best to isolate the cause by copy/pasting the sub-selects into separate queries and troubleshooting each one individually.  Once you get each one working, add each one back-in and test.  The problem in the query was an extra comma after "CallsPending".  I fixed it in the example(above).

Answer (score 1):

Each column can be calculated, mostly with iif statements:

```
Total calls = count(calls)

Closed calls = sum(iif(<call is closed>,1,0)  (however you define <call is closed>)

Closed in 5 days = sum(iif(<call is closed in 5 days>,1,0))
```

and so on